# python conda deployment on server

Tags: python, deployment, server, environment, conda

Let say I have two projects that I develop on my personal machine. I use conda to manage my python dependencies. I created environments to manage these projects. When I'm done with the dev, I want to export them to a remote machine that will run regularly, in the same time, these two projects. **How should I manage this deployment ?**

Comment: Can you please restrict your post to a single question? Thank you! Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some researches, I came up with this:

- clone your environments as described on [conda's doc](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html).
- export your environment file on the server along with your project.
- import the environment on the server's conda.
- create a bash script like that

`#!/bin/bash
source activate my_environment
python ~/my_project/src/code.py`

- set up [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) as usual calling this previous bash script